# How to prove an asymmetric voting system with 99.9% success rate cannot be beaten?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I would like to attempt the question proposed in the [following talk](https://soundcloud.com/university-of-cambridge/clueless-voting?in=university-of-cambridge/sets/cambridge-science-festival-2) (at minute 51:23).

The asymmetric voting system is given in [these minutes](http://tms.soc.srcf.net/docs/imre101005.pdf).

The summarised question is:

```
"Can you prove 99.9% success with this system is the best case?"
```

How would I approach proving that this success rate cannot be improved by another voting system?

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Answer (score 1):

The underlying question is

> There are $n$ people in a room, each of whom has a piece of paper stuck to their forehead, with either a $0$ or a $1$ written on it. The $0$s and $1$s occur independently and with equal probability. Everyone has to vote on the parity of the sum of all the $0$s and $1$s in the room. Everyone has a $50-50$ chance of guessing correctly — they all can see what everyone else's number is, but they have no idea what their own is.

The proposed optimal solution involves people ordering themselves and deciding how to vote and weighting their votes according to what they see on everyone else's foreheads and whether or not they are certain that those earlier in the order will collectively reach a correct decision. This weighting is why it is described as an *asymmetric* voting system.

(The precise weighting proposal is that if you are certain that those earlier in the order will collectively reach a correct decision then you weight your vote so small that you do not affect the collective vote, while if you are not certain then you weight your vote so large that it will overwhelm the votes of all those earlier in the order.  Either way, your actual vote can be arbitrary so long as how you reach it is known to the others: for simplicity it could just be voting as if you had a $0$ on your forehead and combining this with what you see on the other foreheads to decide the overall parity; you then decide your weighting based on whether you see anybody earlier than you in the order has a $0$ on their forehead and so will make a correct vote.)

There are $2^n$ equally probable patterns of $0$s and $1$s. At least one of these patterns will defeat any voting system. So the probability of any voting system failing is at least $\frac1{2^n}$ and the probability of it succeeding cannot exceed $1-\frac1{2^n}$.  When $n=10$ the probability of success cannot exceed $0.9990234375$, about $99.9\%$.  The method proposed in the brackets is only defeated by one pattern, namely all $1$s, so it reaches this figure and is optimal as no other voting method can do better.